# The data cannot be updated to the local host in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SForU.png)Could anyone help me, please? I am learning Java MVC on YouTube. When it comes to building the controller for the web, I followed the same steps as others. However, when I try to update the data, my localhost remains unchanged from the initial state. I've been searching for the error for a while but can't figure out what's causing it. I'm using IntelliJ and Postgres. Here is my code. Thank you
[https://github.com/VuQuocLong21092003/java_mvc/tree/master/src/main/java/com/rungroop/web[enter](https://github.com/VuQuocLong21092003/java_mvc/tree/master/src/main/java/com/rungroop/web%5Benter) image description here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPWdh.png)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where are you updating what, and what is an initital localhost state? You provide no code, not result, no expected behavior, nothing to work with.

Comment: I am connected to PostgreSQL, and I have the code with sections such as controller, model, DTO, service, etc. When I try to update an image to the database that I have connected, I have copied the entire HTML file similar to the one on YouTube that I learned from. However, when they update the image to the database, they have the image displayed, but in my case, it does not work

Comment: Neither will I explore your Github project to find the specific code segment you are talking about, nor will I watch the Youtube video to get a grasp of what you wanna achieve. Maybe you wanna take a closer look to other questions how they put the relevant code into the question, give examples of how they work with it and apply expected output. In the end, you are just telling a story and expect that we will encouter your problem somehow and provide a solution. Please: ***PUT CODE AND WORKFLOW INTO QUESTION***.